# How to make smooth animation keyframes?

Tags: jquery, css, svg, css-animations

I am new to css3 animations. I have this code that animations the feet of the svg. But the problem is the movement is not smooth when it changes keyframes. From 0% code block to 33% code block, it feels like there is a delay. It feels like its instantaneously changing degrees, when it should be more smooth. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>


        <style>

            @keyframes example {
                0% {
                    transform:rotate(0deg);
                }
                33% {
                    transform:rotate(45deg);
                }
                66% {
                    transform:rotate(-45deg);
                }
                100% {
                    transform:rotate(0deg);
                }
            }
            #left_leg_group {
                animation: example 1s infinite;
                transform-origin: 50% -10%;
            } 
            #right_leg_group {
                animation: example 1s infinite;
                transform-origin: 50% -10%;
                animation-delay:0.1s;
            } 
        </style>


    </head>

    <body>



        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px"
             height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
        <g id="main">
        <g id="left_leg_group">
            <rect id="left_1" x="81" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40"/>
            <rect x="81" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5"/>
            <path id="foot" fill="#A07044" d="M98,180H75c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S75,169,75,169h23V180z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="torso_group">
            <path fill="#653508" d="M138,141H63V65.021c0,0-1.751-29.521,37.167-29.521S138,65.021,138,65.021V141z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="right_leg_group">
                <rect id="Left_3_" x="109" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40"/>
                <rect x="109" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5"/>
                <path id="foot_1_" fill="#AE7A49" d="M126,180h-23c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S103,169,103,169h23V180z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="right_arm_group">
                <path fill="#653508" d="M138,73.21c0,0-13,0.123-13,4.957s13,5.824,13,5.824c1,0.01,0.725,0.01,1.005,0.01
                    c17.58,0,31.747-14.25,31.747-31.83c0-17.19-13.752-31.2-30.752-31.81v11.43c10,1.98,19.67,10.43,19.67,20.55
                    C159.67,63.15,149,72.05,138,73.21z"/>
                <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M133.33,25.75c0,5.25,4.835,5.72,4.835,5.72c0.67,0.07,1.835,0.18,1.835,0.32V20.36
                    c0-0.01-0.605-0.02-0.995-0.02c-0.28,0-0.478,0-0.757,0.01C138.248,20.35,133.33,20.5,133.33,25.75z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="left_arm_group">
                <path fill="#653508" d="M41.206,52.34C41.206,42.22,51,33.77,61,31.79V20.36c-17,0.61-30.876,14.62-30.876,31.81
                    C30.124,69.75,44.229,84,61.809,84c0.281,0-0.025,0,0.975-0.01c0,0,12.984-0.99,12.984-5.824c0-4.833-12.946-4.956-12.946-4.956
                    C51.821,72.05,41.206,63.15,41.206,52.34z"/>
                <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M67.422,25.75c0,5.25-4.711,5.72-4.711,5.72C62.041,31.54,61,31.65,61,31.79V20.36
                    c0-0.01,0.481-0.02,0.871-0.02c0.28,0,0.416,0,0.695,0.01C62.566,20.35,67.422,20.5,67.422,25.75z"/>
        </g>
        <g id="head_group">
            <circle id="face" fill="#AE7A49" cx="95.207" cy="70.543" r="28.042"/>
            <path id="Right_Eye" fill="#200200" d="M82.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.07-2.38-2.38-2.38s-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
                c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S82.25,62.38,82.25,65z"/>
            <path id="left_eye_1" fill="#200200" d="M106.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.069-2.38-2.38-2.38c-1.31,0-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
                c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S106.25,62.38,106.25,65z"/>
            <circle id="mouth" fill="#200200" cx="89.104" cy="70.938" r="5.271"/>
            <polygon id="forehead" fill="#915B36" points="104,51 81,51 81.688,49 103.312,49     "/>
            <polygon id="forehead_1" fill="#915B36" points="110,56 76,56 76.75,54 109.125,54    "/>
        </g>
        </g>
        </svg>



    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an animation timing, like `linear`, so that it doesn't move immediately from step to step. Read more about [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) here. It can be added directly into the `animation` shorthand like so:

```css
@keyframes example {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    33% {
        transform:rotate(45deg);
    }
    66% {
        transform:rotate(-45deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
}
#left_leg_group {
    animation: example 1s linear infinite; /* here */
    transform-origin: 50% -10%;
}
#right_leg_group {
    animation: example 1s linear infinite; /* and here*/
    transform-origin: 50% -10%;
    animation-delay:0.1s;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="main">
        <g id="left_leg_group">
            <rect id="left_1" x="81" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40" />
            <rect x="81" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5" />
            <path id="foot" fill="#A07044" d="M98,180H75c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S75,169,75,169h23V180z" />
        </g>
        <g id="torso_group">
            <path fill="#653508" d="M138,141H63V65.021c0,0-1.751-29.521,37.167-29.521S138,65.021,138,65.021V141z" />
        </g>
        <g id="right_leg_group">
            <rect id="Left_3_" x="109" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40" />
            <rect x="109" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5" />
            <path id="foot_1_" fill="#AE7A49" d="M126,180h-23c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S103,169,103,169h23V180z" />
        </g>
        <g id="right_arm_group">
            <path fill="#653508" d="M138,73.21c0,0-13,0.123-13,4.957s13,5.824,13,5.824c1,0.01,0.725,0.01,1.005,0.01
                    c17.58,0,31.747-14.25,31.747-31.83c0-17.19-13.752-31.2-30.752-31.81v11.43c10,1.98,19.67,10.43,19.67,20.55
                    C159.67,63.15,149,72.05,138,73.21z" />
            <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M133.33,25.75c0,5.25,4.835,5.72,4.835,5.72c0.67,0.07,1.835,0.18,1.835,0.32V20.36
                    c0-0.01-0.605-0.02-0.995-0.02c-0.28,0-0.478,0-0.757,0.01C138.248,20.35,133.33,20.5,133.33,25.75z" />
        </g>
        <g id="left_arm_group">
            <path fill="#653508" d="M41.206,52.34C41.206,42.22,51,33.77,61,31.79V20.36c-17,0.61-30.876,14.62-30.876,31.81
                    C30.124,69.75,44.229,84,61.809,84c0.281,0-0.025,0,0.975-0.01c0,0,12.984-0.99,12.984-5.824c0-4.833-12.946-4.956-12.946-4.956
                    C51.821,72.05,41.206,63.15,41.206,52.34z" />
            <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M67.422,25.75c0,5.25-4.711,5.72-4.711,5.72C62.041,31.54,61,31.65,61,31.79V20.36
                    c0-0.01,0.481-0.02,0.871-0.02c0.28,0,0.416,0,0.695,0.01C62.566,20.35,67.422,20.5,67.422,25.75z" />
        </g>
        <g id="head_group">
            <circle id="face" fill="#AE7A49" cx="95.207" cy="70.543" r="28.042" />
            <path id="Right_Eye" fill="#200200" d="M82.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.07-2.38-2.38-2.38s-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
                c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S82.25,62.38,82.25,65z" />
            <path id="left_eye_1" fill="#200200" d="M106.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.069-2.38-2.38-2.38c-1.31,0-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
                c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S106.25,62.38,106.25,65z" />
            <circle id="mouth" fill="#200200" cx="89.104" cy="70.938" r="5.271" />
            <polygon id="forehead" fill="#915B36" points="104,51 81,51 81.688,49 103.312,49     " />
            <polygon id="forehead_1" fill="#915B36" points="110,56 76,56 76.75,54 109.125,54    " />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: On chrome (where the origin rule works) it doesn't seem that smooth still.

Comment: @omega That's probably a case of the individual keyframes (0%, 33%, 66%, etc.) and how much rotation is going on within the animation's duration of 1s. That is, by 500ms, it's already rotated to 45 deg AND back to -45 deg. Try slowing it down by animating it from 0 to 45deg back to 0 at 0%, 50%, and 100%).

Comment: @omega What version of Chrome are you using? It looks pretty smooth to me: http://jsfiddle.net/w78Laxwt/1/ You can also use timings like `ease-in`, `ease`, `ease-out`, or `ease-in-out`. Personally, I would recommend `ease-in-out`.

Comment: @omega Did any of that help?

Answer (score 0):

May be what makes it look ugly is stopping at the 0deg positions.

What about that ? (removed the 0deg step, and placed the remaining steps evenly

```css
@keyframes example {
      0% {  transform:rotate(45deg);}
     50% {  transform:rotate(-45deg);}
    100% {  transform:rotate(45deg);}
}
#left_leg_group {
    animation: example 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    transform-origin: 50% -10%;
} 
#right_leg_group {
    animation: example 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    transform-origin: 50% -10%;
    animation-delay:0.1s;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="main">
        <g id="left_leg_group">
            <rect id="left_1" x="81" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40" />
            <rect x="81" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5" />
            <path id="foot" fill="#A07044" d="M98,180H75c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S75,169,75,169h23V180z" />
        </g>
        <g id="torso_group">
            <path fill="#653508" d="M138,141H63V65.021c0,0-1.751-29.521,37.167-29.521S138,65.021,138,65.021V141z" />
        </g>
        <g id="right_leg_group">
            <rect id="Left_3_" x="109" y="129" fill="#653508" width="17" height="40" />
            <rect x="109" y="141" fill="#3B2111" width="17" height="5" />
            <path id="foot_1_" fill="#AE7A49" d="M126,180h-23c0,0-4.875-0.021-4.875-5.625S103,169,103,169h23V180z" />
        </g>
        <g id="right_arm_group">
            <path fill="#653508" d="M138,73.21c0,0-13,0.123-13,4.957s13,5.824,13,5.824c1,0.01,0.725,0.01,1.005,0.01
                    c17.58,0,31.747-14.25,31.747-31.83c0-17.19-13.752-31.2-30.752-31.81v11.43c10,1.98,19.67,10.43,19.67,20.55
                    C159.67,63.15,149,72.05,138,73.21z" />
            <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M133.33,25.75c0,5.25,4.835,5.72,4.835,5.72c0.67,0.07,1.835,0.18,1.835,0.32V20.36
                    c0-0.01-0.605-0.02-0.995-0.02c-0.28,0-0.478,0-0.757,0.01C138.248,20.35,133.33,20.5,133.33,25.75z" />
        </g>
        <g id="left_arm_group">
            <path fill="#653508" d="M41.206,52.34C41.206,42.22,51,33.77,61,31.79V20.36c-17,0.61-30.876,14.62-30.876,31.81
                    C30.124,69.75,44.229,84,61.809,84c0.281,0-0.025,0,0.975-0.01c0,0,12.984-0.99,12.984-5.824c0-4.833-12.946-4.956-12.946-4.956
                    C51.821,72.05,41.206,63.15,41.206,52.34z" />
            <path fill="#AE7A49" d="M67.422,25.75c0,5.25-4.711,5.72-4.711,5.72C62.041,31.54,61,31.65,61,31.79V20.36
                    c0-0.01,0.481-0.02,0.871-0.02c0.28,0,0.416,0,0.695,0.01C62.566,20.35,67.422,20.5,67.422,25.75z" />
        </g>
        <g id="head_group">
            <circle id="face" fill="#AE7A49" cx="95.207" cy="70.543" r="28.042" />
            <path id="Right_Eye" fill="#200200" d="M82.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.07-2.38-2.38-2.38s-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
                c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S82.25,62.38,82.25,65z" />
            <path id="left_eye_1" fill="#200200" d="M106.25,65h-2.37c0-1.31-1.069-2.38-2.38-2.38c-1.31,0-2.38,1.07-2.38,2.38h-2.37
                c0-2.62,2.13-4.75,4.75-4.75S106.25,62.38,106.25,65z" />
            <circle id="mouth" fill="#200200" cx="89.104" cy="70.938" r="5.271" />
            <polygon id="forehead" fill="#915B36" points="104,51 81,51 81.688,49 103.312,49     " />
            <polygon id="forehead_1" fill="#915B36" points="110,56 76,56 76.75,54 109.125,54    " />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```